# Problems with NumPy version with Python 3.10

Tags: python, numpy

Need help please with fixing the NumPy problem I have. Tried to fix it for 2 days and didn't get far.

I have installed Python 3.10. I am using PyCharm.
When I debug my app I keep on getting the following error:

```
{Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\PaySlip_New\\main.py\", line 2, in <module>\r\n  
  from src.common.ParserFactory import ParserFactory\r\n  
File \"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\PaySlip_New\\src\\common\\ParserFactory.py\", line 1, in <module>\r\n   
 from src.parsers.regular_parser import Parser\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\PaySlip_New\\src\\parsers\\regular_parser.py\", line 1, in <module>\r\n    from src.common.ParserMain import ParserMain\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\PaySlip_New\\src\\common\\ParserMain.py\", line 1, in <module>\r\n  
  import pandas as pd\r\n  File \"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\PaySlip_New\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\__init__.py\", 
line 16, in <module>\r\n   
 raise ImportError(\r\nImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:\r\nnumpy: \r\n\r\nIMPORTANT: 
PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!\r\n\r\nImporting the numpy C-extensions failed. 
This error can happen for\r\nmany reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was\r\ninstalled.\r\n\r\nWe 
have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:\r\n\r\n   
 https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html\r\n\r\nPlease note and check the following:\r\n\r\n  * T
he Python version is: Python3.10 from \"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\PycharmProjects\\PaySlip_New\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe\"\r\n  
* The NumPy version is: \"1.19.4\"\r\n\r\nand make sure that they are the versions you expect.\r\nPlease carefully study the documentation 
linked above for further help.\r\n\r\nOriginal error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'\r\n\r\n}
```

When I run cmd version I get this:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>pip3 show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.21.4
```

pypvenv.cfg

```
home = C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.10.6.final.0
virtualenv = 20.13.0
```

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Numpy 1.21 seems to only support Python 3.7-3.9. Consider updating numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says "Numpy version is 1.19.4", but you expect it to be version 1.21.4. Your pandas version seems to be incompatible with numpy 1.19.4.